# tweet sharp authentication don't return access token

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, twitter, tweetsharp

tweet sharp authentication  don't return access token
when i make authentication with my account access token back (Y)
but when i use another account no access token back ?
this is code

==========================

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetTwitterToken();
        }


private void GetTwitterToken()
        {
            service = new TwitterService(TwitterSettings.ConsumerKey, TwitterSettings.ConsumerKeySecret);
            var cb = new Action<OAuthRequestToken, TwitterResponse>(CallBackToken);
            service.GetRequestToken("oob", CallBackToken);
        }


void CallBackToken(OAuthRequestToken rt, TwitterResponse response)
        {
            Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(rt);
            _requestToken = rt;
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { BrowserControl.Navigate(uri); }));
        }


private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pinText.Text))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter PIN");
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var cb = new Action<OAuthAccessToken, TwitterResponse>(CallBackVerifiedResponse);
                    service.GetAccessToken(_requestToken, pinText.Text, CallBackVerifiedResponse);
                    BrowserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }
        }

void CallBackVerifiedResponse(OAuthAccessToken at, TwitterResponse response)
        {
            if (at != null)
           {


                Settings1.Default.AccessToken = at.Token;
                Settings1.Default.AccessTokenSecret = at.TokenSecret;
                Settings1.Default.ScreenName = at.ScreenName;
                Settings1.Default.UserId = at.UserId.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(at.ScreenName);


           }
        }
```

any one can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution thanks....

just download tweet sharp unofficial from nugget its solve the problem

and i find the problem in the tweetsharp.service.getaccesstoken("",pintxt);

when back the user profile user id is long than int64 so the new  users in twitter and user id taller than or users that less than well back null so in the unofficial tweetsharp they solve that problem